# Maintaining state in a pagination handler

Tags: javascript, pagination, closure

In my application I wrote a pagination code that retrieves data from the server as the user scrolls down. In this case, I need to mantain the current page, whether a request is being processed, and whether the server has more data to serve. I didn't want to use globals, but still needed to mantain these 3 variables state.

Here's my code:

```
fetchNextNotificationPage = (function() {

    var currentPage = 0;
    var maxPageHit = false;
    var fetching = false;

    return function () {

        // Prevent firing concurrent or pointless requests.
        if (fetching || maxPageHit) return;

        fetching = true;

       $.getJSON("GetPageUrl", { page: currentPage + 1 }, function (data) {

           if (!data.error) {

               // Finished fetching, so now it is safe
               // to say we are at previous page + 1.
               currentPage += 1;

               updateData(data.page);

               if (data.lastPage) {
                   maxPageHit = true;
               }
           }
           else {

               console.log(data.error);
           }

       }).always(function() {.

           fetching = false;
       });
   };
}());
```

Is there a better way to solve this other than using closure?

Comment: If you are using ES6 you can use either let or consts. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right approaches, however, you can generalize your implementations, for example, on the second approach:

```
function installHandler ( that, eventName, userOneTime, userRegular ) {
    that.on(eventName, function ( event ) {
        that.off(eventName).on(eventName, userRegular);
        userOneTime ( event );
        userRegular ( event );
    });
}

installHandler ( $(this), "click", 
    function () { alert ("special click"); }, 
    function () { alert ("regular click"); } );
```